# Brainfuck. How check on palindrome?

Tags: brainfuck

The problem is to check if sequence is palindrome using **Brainfuck**.

**input** is a sequance of numbers

**output** 0 if it is not palindorme, else 1.

***I have one idea:***
Say, we have sequance *1 2 3 2 1*. We can memorise first cell from our array in variable(do this using operation *'!'*),

- then change 1 to 0(do this using operation *'0'*),array will be 0 2 3 2 1,
- then  we go to the end of array until we meet 0 (do this using
  *'>[>]'*),
- then  we take number from variable and get sequance *0 2 3 2 1 1.*
- **Next** step should be to compare two last numbers, if they are equal continue algo from begining else do something...

I do not know how to implement last step.

Comment: where are we on this question ? was my response helpful ?

Answer (score 2):

please excuse me if I won't write the entire program in brainfuck,

This is the main idea:

1. Read input (pointer should be at last character afterwards)
2. memorize character
3. Set value to 0
4. Go to first [<]
5. Compare to memorized character (see [Brainfuck compare 2 numbers as greater than or less than](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168584/brainfuck-compare-2-numbers-as-greater-than-or-less-than))
6. If not equal, print 1
7. If the next (>) cell array is 0, print 0
8. Move to pointer to end [>]
9. Go back to step 2

Comment: `2. memorize character` - how ?

Comment: @Scony I think he means read the input and add it to the tape with the `,` command.